# "No application in the DB with the id" error when invoking adapter procedures from client applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

On a Windows 7 machine, i have installed:

- Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 64 bit edition,
- IBM Worklight Studio version 6.1.0 from Eclipse Marketplace
- ADT

I am  getting an error while trying to invoke an adapter procedure from a client application. 
I am following [this training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_06_Invoking_adapter_procedures_from_client_applications.pdf)

I haven't coded this application on my own. Rather [I downloaded the associated sample](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/InvokingAdapterProceduresProject.zip) of the above training module.

I deployed the adapter that is part of the sample and successfully tested the adapter procedures by using the option `Run As --> Invoke Worklight procedure`

Now when i enable the android environment and try to run this app (the html and the associated js is trying to invoke the js procedures), i get the following errors and the application doesn't run as expected

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application
>   in the DB with the id 'InvokeAdapterProcedure'. [project
>   InvokeAdapterProcedure] [ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error
>   description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal
>   error occurred during gadget request  [project
>   InvokeAdapterProcedure]There is no application in the DB with the id
>   'InvokeAdapterProcedure'., User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null,
>   wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null,
>   SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null,
>   wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null,
>   wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}.
>   [project InvokeAdapterProcedure] 
>                                                                                                                  com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter

I can very well see the application installed under the Worklight server (in the servers view)

What exactly is wrong?

I imported this app back to WL 6.0 and i was able to successfully run it there. So, is this a issue with WL 6.1?

Comment: This is how the app looks when run in the preview mode http://i.stack.imgur.com/7WhAc.png and this is the servers view showing the app alongwith the adapter correctly deployed in the WL server http://i.stack.imgur.com/vQMSn.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Worklight does not support Eclipse Standard. Rather, you should use [Eclipse Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1).

Second, have you deployed both the application and adapter?
I've done the following steps and the application works for me:

1. Imported the [Adapter Procedures sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/InvokingAdapterProceduresProject.zip) .zip file
2. Opened the adapters folder, right-clicked on the `RSSReader` adapter and chose `Run As > Deploy Worklight Adapter`
3. Opened the apps folder, right-clicked on the `InvokeAdapterProcedure` app and chose `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server`
4. Right-clicked on the Worklight project and chose `Open Worklight Console`
5. Clicked on `Preview as Common Resources`

The result was: 
[image]

I also tested this when adding the Android environment and previewing it via Worklight Console's MBS, as well as an in a real Android device.

Make sure that after adding the Android environment you build and deploy the application by choosing `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Idan, thanks for the quick reply. I did install Eclipse Java EE, basically whatever was instructed in the Worklight download url.

Comment: So don't write Standard... :-) What about the rest?

Comment: The problem is resolved now. I missed the  Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server part. I never used to do this on WL 6.0 and so skipped this step. But thanks, i now know this step has to be performed too.

Have edited my question to indicate that Eclipse Java EE was used.

Comment: "Run on Worklight Development Server" is the new "Build and Deploy".